# ImageView With Tag

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm making a drawing app where on click new imageview is created and they are saved in an array. after creation of multiple views i have added a functionality to delete any view on touch. how can I do this?

```
if indexPath.item == 0 {
  user = cell.pipeImages
  user!.tag = editablePipes.count + 1
  self.editablePipes.append(user!)

 if(editablePipes.indices.contains(0)) {
    let imageArt = editablePipes[0].image
    user = UIImageView(image: imageArt)
    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Generator.PipeImage1(_:)))
    user!.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    user!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad) {
      user!.frame = CGRect(x: 400, y: 40, width: 50, height: 50)
    } else {
      user!.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 20, width: 30, height: 30)
    }

    view.addSubview(user!)
  }


    if touch.view == user { // Touch that view
        if editablePipes.count != 0 {
            var a = "\(view.viewWithTag(editablePipes))"
            editablePipes.remove(at: a) //after touch on view how can I get that tag and delete it?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any visuals you can share?

Comment: its simple image, delete after click on delete button

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you want to achieve and what is not working for you in your code?

Comment: this is a drawing app where new imageview is created and appended in array with tag as you can see in code when you click on a cell , but when user want to delete that image view how he can delete that imageview ??